# .net chooses wrong method to call, based on aruments type

Tags: c#, overloading, derived-class

I have two Data classes: ***BaseDataClass*** and ***DerivedDataClass*** which derives from first one.
I also have two Consuming classes: ***ConsumingBaseClass*** and ***ConsumingDerivedClass*** which derives from first one.
In ***ConsumingBaseClass*** I have virtual method ***DoWork***, which accepts ***DerivedDataClass*** and do some work.

In ***ConsumingDerivedClass*** I have override for method ***DoWork*** and also I have overload for ***DoWork*** which accepts ***BaseDataClass***.
When I try to call ***DoWork***, passing instance of ***DerivedDataClass***, ***DoWork(BaseDataClass)*** is called instead of ***DoWork(DerivedDataClass)***.

**Have anybody idea, why wrong method is called?**

Following code demostrates the problem:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsumingDerivedClass x = new ConsumingDerivedClass();
        // Wrong DoWork is called - expected calling of DoWork(DerivedDataClass) but actually called DoWork(BaseDataClass)
        x.DoWork(new DerivedDataClass());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class ConsumingBaseClass
{
    public virtual void DoWork(DerivedDataClass instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConsumingBaseClass.DoWork(DerivedDataClass); Type of argument is '{0}'", instance.GetType());
    }
}

public class ConsumingDerivedClass : ConsumingBaseClass
{
    public override void DoWork(DerivedDataClass instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConsumingDerivedClass.DoWork(DerivedDataClass); Type of argument is '{0}'", instance.GetType());
        base.DoWork(instance);
        // Some additional logic
    }

    public void DoWork(BaseDataClass instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConsumingDerivedClass.DoWork(BaseDataClass); Type of argument is '{0}'", instance.GetType());
        DerivedDataClass derivedInstance = new DerivedDataClass();
        // Some logic based on what is in baseInstacne
        derivedInstance.SomeProperty = "Value, got from some logic";

        base.DoWork(derivedInstance);
        // Some additional logic
    }
}

public class BaseDataClass
{ }

public class DerivedDataClass : BaseDataClass
{ 
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Have anybody idea, why wrong method is called?

The right method is being called according to the language specification. It's your expectations which are wrong.

> In ConsumingDerivedClass I have override for method DoWork and also I have overload for DoWork which accepts BaseDataClass.

That's the problem, basically. Overload resolution doesn't work the way you think it does. The compiler works from the compile-time type of the target of the call, up through base classes towards `object`. Only methods *newly declared* (not even overridden) are considered.

You can change which overload would be used by writing:

```
((ConsumingBaseClass) x).DoWork(new DerivedDataClass());
```

Ideally though, if you've got something this brittle, it would be worth giving the methods different names. Overloads should have the same effect, just providing information in different ways.

Basically, have a look at the first question on my [brainteasers page](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers.html), and the details of the first answer. I also have an [article on overload resolution](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) which you may find useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your base method to use BaseDataClass and override that.  Provide the Derived data specific version as the "new" method (as per @Jon Skeet's answer)

```
class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsumingDerivedClass x = new ConsumingDerivedClass();
            // Wrong DoWork is called - expected calling of DoWork(DerivedDataClass) but actually called DoWork(BaseDataClass) 
            x.DoWork(new DerivedDataClass());
            x.DoWork(new BaseDataClass());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class ConsumingBaseClass
    {
        public virtual void DoWork(BaseDataClass instance)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ConsumingBaseClass.DoWork(DerivedDataClass); Type of argument is '{0}'", instance.GetType());
        }
    }

    public class ConsumingDerivedClass : ConsumingBaseClass
    {
        public override void DoWork(BaseDataClass instance)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ConsumingDerivedClass.DoWork(DerivedDataClass); Type of argument is '{0}'", instance.GetType());
            base.DoWork(instance);
            // Some additional logic 
        }

        public void DoWork(DerivedDataClass instance)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ConsumingDerivedClass.DoWork(BaseDataClass); Type of argument is '{0}'", instance.GetType());
            DerivedDataClass derivedInstance = new DerivedDataClass();
            // Some logic based on what is in baseInstacne 
            derivedInstance.SomeProperty = "Value, got from some logic";

            base.DoWork(derivedInstance);
            // Some additional logic 
        }
    }

    public class BaseDataClass
    { }

    public class DerivedDataClass : BaseDataClass
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
```